# Maven with sonar authentication

Tags: maven, sonarqube

I am running maven with sonar. Since I activated authentication on sonar for security purposes, since then I got the following error:

```
[ERROR] Can´t access to Sonar or project doesn't exist on Sonar instance. HTTP KO to http://localhost:9000/api/resources?resource=com.myproject.soft:soft&depth=0&format=xml
java.io.IOException: Can´t access to Sonar or project doesn't exist on Sonar instance.
        at org.sonar.report.pdf.util.SonarAccess.getUrlAsDocument(SonarAccess.java:132)
        at org.sonar.report.pdf.entity.Project.initializeProject(Project.java:98)
```

according to http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+with+Maven I should use the following parameters:

```
-Dsonar.login=login -Dsonar.password=password
```

Those settings are not working for me.

The full command I am using is:

```
mvn install sonar:sonar -Dsonar.login=login -Dsonar.password=password
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a limitation of the [PDF Report Plugin](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Sonar+PDF+Plugin) that is developed by Klicap:

http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONARPLUGINS-1510

If you remove this plugin, then everything should be back to normal.

Comment: Remove it on the server ?

Comment: Yes, indeed, the JAR should be removed from "extensions/plugins" folder.

Comment: Didn't want to remove the pdf plugin as I wasn't sure if it would be needed later. I got this to work using Maven and modifying my settings.xml and the sonar profile by adding    <sonar.pdf.username> <sonar.pdf.password> properties

Answer (score 1):

We have the same problem and resolved it by adding some credentials. Tested on Sonar 3.7 and Sonar PDF Plugin 1.3

In eclipse put this as your maven Goals:

```
org.codehaus.sonar-plugins.pdf-report:maven-pdfreport-plugin:1.3:generate -Dsonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000 -Dreport.type=executive -Dsonar.pdf.username=admin -Dsonar.pdf.password=admin
```